# Flutter local_auth , I want to get fingerprint signature so I can encrypt it with password

Tags: flutter, dart, localauthentication

Is there a way to obtain a unique fingerprint signature of the user using the local_auth package (Flutter/Dart) so that I can encrypt it along with a password and store it? (Reference: https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth/example)